# Preload Background Image from ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I've created a function which will allow a client to have a different background on his homepage based upon the day of the week. I have four different sizes of the image based on the screen width of various devices. I'd like to find a way to get the background images to preload so that the page loads more smoothly. Here is the function with the preload towards the bottom. This currently loads the last size "phone_background" only, but I'd like it to preload the corresponding size for the visitor's device. Grateful for any suggestions.

function my_custom_background() {

```
if ( ! is_front_page() ) {
    return;
}

$img_id = get_field( strtolower( date( 'l' ) ) );

echo "<style>\n";

// Large desktops.
$size = 'large_desktop_background';
$img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $img_id, 'large_desktop_background' );


echo "body {\n";
echo sprintf( "\tbackground-image: url(%s);\n", $img[0] );
echo "}\n";


// Small desktops.

$size = 'small_desktop_background';
$img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $img_id, 'small_desktop_background' );

echo "@media (max-width: 1199px) {\n";
echo "\tbody {\n";
echo sprintf( "\t\tbackground-image: url(%s);\n", $img[0] );
echo "\t}\n";
echo "}\n";


// Tablets.
$size = 'tablet_background';
$img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $img_id, 'tablet_background' );

echo "@media (max-width: 991px) {\n";
echo "\tbody {\n";
echo sprintf( "\t\tbackground-image: url(%s);\n", $img[0] );
echo "\t}\n";
echo "}\n";

// Mobile.
$size = 'phone_background';
$img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $img_id, 'phone_background' );

echo "@media (max-width: 767px) {\n";
echo "\tbody {\n";
echo sprintf( "\t\tbackground-image: url(%s);\n", $img[0] );
echo "\t}\n";
echo "}\n";

echo "</style>\n";

$preload = "<div style='display:none;'>
<img src= '$img[0]' />
</div>";
echo $preload;

}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_custom_background' );
```

Comment: Check out a lazy loader like [lazysizes](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes).
Side note: Images in elements set to `display:none` will *not* load. Also that `div` won't do anything as it's output inside the `<head>`…

Comment: Thanks so much! Do you have a recommendation as to how to add the img class "lazyload" in the above scenario?